# Filereader output saved to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, filereader

I would like to ask you guys, how to save output of FileReader in JavaScript to a variable, or make the function where is the FileReader return the output.

Here is also a bit of code:

**HTML**

```
<input type='file' id='inputFile'>
<button id='btn'>Save</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function imgToBase64(file_input) {
    if (file_input.files && file_input.files[0]) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            result = event.target.result;
            return result // ???
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file_input.files[0]);
    }
}

parameter = document.getElementById('inputFile');
btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  variable = imgToBase64(parameter); //in this variable I would like to store the result from that function
}
```

I found out that the FileReader is asynchronous and i need a callback or smth, but I don't fully understand how to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AngularJS's [$q promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to get the result.  Just make sure to inject $q wherever you create the imgToBase64 function.

```
function imgToBase64(file_input) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (file_input.files && file_input.files[0]) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            result = event.target.result;
            deferred.resolve(result);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file_input.files[0]);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}

parameter = document.getElementById('inputFile');
btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
    imgToBase64(parameter).then(function (result) {
        variable = result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask you if you have any idea how can I pass to that function 'imgToBase64()' an array of inputs, and than save the result to the array of results? Thanks :)

Comment: @marek Search stack overflow for an answer to that and post it as a question if you don't see one, I'll keep an eye out for it.